# Дублируются данные в таблицу Базы

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Всем привет.
При вводе данных через инпут или код после перезагрузки страницы. дублируются записи в таблице БД.
Почему?!
Код прилагаю

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    echo $email;
    echo $password;

    $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'firstbase');

    

    if($connection) {
        echo "Database is connected";

    } else {
        die('Connection is failed');
    }

    $query = "INSERT INTO users (user_name, email, password) VALUES ('Stas', '67890@mail.ru', '09876');";

    $query_result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    if (!$query_result) {
        die("Query failed".mysqli_error());
    }

}




?>
```

[image: Таблица]

Comment: потому что ф5 после обработки post запроса отправляет форму повторно, о чем бразуер обычно предупреждает. Для избежания этого поведения после обработки пост делают редирект на гет с выборкой вставленных данных при необходимости.

Comment: Спасибо. А как это поправить в рамках показанного кода?